# Facebook Multi request

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, multi-friend-selector

I would like to embed the facebook request form on the fan page without asking for permission, is it possible that the friend selector does not popup but instead displayed on the fan page?

The problem I am facing is

1. As I do not want to bother user for permissions I do not have the Current UserId, which I need for computation of who send how many request
2. Do not want the app request to popup
3. Do not want to use the fbml as it will get deprecated by June 2012

Any help how can I do this using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

As you say yourself, you need the current user id. I'm sure you can get this without permissions along with other basic data such as name and gender etc.

try:

`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=YOURUSERID`and you'll see.

As for showing the multi-friend selector in the page rather than as a popup, I've not done it myself but usually you can specify the display parameter, e.g. `&display=page (rather than display=popup`

Also, I think you have to use the JS SDK to do this and not PHP:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Also, if you want to send notifications to your user's friends then you will require permissions to do so.

Comment: path=YOURUSERID  (I donot know how to get YOURUSERID of current user visiting my fanpage without asking for permission)
I need to fetch the current user user_id , I read facebook  documentation but donot know how can I get the userId of the person visiting my fanpage.

Comment: You cannot know the user ID of your visitor UNLESS your app has a valid auth token for them.  If you could get it without, then it'd be a privacy violation.

Comment: ummm... ok I decided to take basic info from user, Is it possible to Embed Friend selector into fanpage?
Do i use some iframe ? Any Idea how can this be done? I donot need popup